# Linux using command file -i return wrong value charset=unknow-8bit for a windows-1252 encoded file

Tags: node.js, linux, file, windows-1252, cp1252

Using nodejs and iconv-lite to create a http response file in xml with charset windows-1252, the file -i command cannot identify it as windows-1252.

Server side:

```
r.header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=teste.xml');
r.header('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=iso8859-1');
r.write(ICONVLITE.encode(`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?><x>€Àáção</x>`, "win1252")); //euro symbol and portuguese accentuated vogals
r.end();
```

The browser donwloads the file and then i check it in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

```
file -i teste.xml
/tmp/teste.xml: text/xml; charset=unknown-8bit
```

When i use gedit to open it, the accentuated vogal appear fine but the euro symbol it does not (all characters from 128 to 159 get messed up).

I checked in a windows 10 vm and in there all goes well. Both in Windows and Linux web browsers, it also shows all fine.

So, is it a problem in file command? How to check the right charsert of a file in Linux?

Thank you

**EDIT**
The result file can be get [here](https://op3racional.eu/lixo.xml)

**2nd EDIT**
I found one error! The code line:

```
    r.header('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=iso8859-1');
```

must be:

```
r.header('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=Windows-1252');
```

Comment: Can you paste the result of `od teste.xml` in your question?

Comment: Yes, sorry... done.

Comment: I replaced the file for the download with the correct one. I also, find out that now this file gives charset unknown-8bit but if i add more charaters on it, it returns iso-8859-1. So, it must trigger by some characters that the result of file -i changes without changing the content-type and the iconv encode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to understand what a character encoding is and isn't.

A text file is actually just a stream of bits; or, since we've mostly agreed that there are 8 bits in a byte, a stream of bytes. A character encoding is a lookup table (and sometimes a more complicated algorithm) for deciding what characters to show to a human for that stream of bytes.

For instance, the character "€" encoded in Windows-1252 is the string of bits `10000000`. That same string of bits will mean other things in other encodings - most encodings assign *some* meaning to all 256 possible bytes.

If a piece of software knows that the file is supposed to be read as Windows-1252, it can look up a mapping for that encoding and show you a "€". This is how browsers are displaying the right thing: you've told them in the Content-Type header to use the Windows-1252 lookup table.

Once you save the file to disk, that "Windows-1252" label form the Content-Type header isn't stored anywhere. So any program looking at that file can see that it contains the string of bits `10000000` but it doesn't know what mapping table to look that up in. Nothing you do in the HTTP headers is going to change that - none of those are going to affect how it's saved on disk.

In this particular case the "file" command *could* look at the "encoding" marker *inside* the XML document, and find the "windows-1252" there. My guess is that it simply doesn't have that functionality. So instead it uses its general logic for guessing an encoding: it's probably something ASCII-compatible, because it starts with the bytes that spell `<?xml` in ASCII; but it's not ASCII itself, because it has bytes outside the range `00000000` to `01111111`; anything beyond that is hard to guess, so output "unknown-8bit".